# Basic form validation

Tags: javascript, validation

I am trying form validation in Javascript, but I am stuck on something.

I have gotten the validation working, but cannot display the contents of each field in the `textarea` of the form at the bottom.

Any idea how I would do this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head> 
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function validate() {

           if( document.myForm.room.value == "" ) {
             alert( "Please select a room option." );
             return false;
           }
           if( document.myForm.activity.value == "" ) {
             alert( "Please select an activity." );
             return false;
           }
           if( document.myForm.hotelname.value == "-1" ) {
             alert( "Please select a hotel name." );
             return false;
           }
           if( document.myForm.name.value == "" ) {
             alert( "Please provide your name." );
             document.myForm.Name.focus() ;
             return false;
           }
           // Use isNaN to check whether there is an illegal number
           if( document.myForm.zip.value == "" ||
                   isNaN( document.myForm.zip.value ) ||
                   document.myForm.zip.value.length != 5 ) {
             alert( "Please provide a zip code in 5 digit format." );
             document.myForm.zip.focus() ;
             return false;
           }
           return( true );
        }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>

    <form name="myForm" action="" onsubmit="return(validate());">

        Type of room: <br />
        <input type="radio" name="room" value="basic">Basic<br>
        <input type="radio" name="room" value="luxury">Luxury

        <br /><br />

        Activity: <br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="activity" value="swimming">Swimming<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="activity" value="fishing">Fishing

        <br /><br />

        Hotel name: <br />
        <select name="hotelname" multiple="multiple">
            <option value="-1" selected>Select...</option>
            <option value="1">Hilton</option>
            <option value="2">Hampton Inn</option>
            <option value="3">Holiday Inn</option>
         </select>

        <br /><br />

        Conferee's name:<input type="text" name="name">

        <br /><br />

        Conferee's zip code:<input type="text" name="zip">

        <br /><br />

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

        <br /><br />

        <textarea rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>

    </form>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Setting the textarea content should be easy using something like document.getElementById("mytextarea").innerHTML( yourcontent ) where you put an id attribute on the textarea id="mytextarea". However if you end up actually submitting the form somewhere that will be irrelevant.

Comment: Mostly not worried about submitting it I am just learning how to work with JS validation and the like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Use isNaN to check whether there is an illegal number
if( document.myForm.zip.value == "" ||
       isNaN( document.myForm.zip.value ) ||
       document.myForm.zip.value.length != 5 ) {
 alert( "Please provide a zip code in 5 digit format." );
 document.myForm.zip.focus() ;
 return false;
}

// create the textarea content string
var fields_contents = "";
fields_content += "room : " + document.myForm.room.value + "\n";
fields_content += "activity : " + document.myForm.activity.value + "\n";
fields_content += "hotelname : " + document.myForm.hotelname.value + "\n";
fields_content += "name : " + document.myForm.name.value + "\n";
fields_content += "zip : " + document.myForm.zip.value + "\n";

//set the textarea content
document.getElementById('my_textarea').value = fields_content;

//and then return false for the form not to be submitted
return false;
```

Notice I use an id to find the textarea : you should add it in your html. 
The `\n` char is line break.

This version implies your form not to be submitted. The thing is that here we get inputs values directly by reading their value property. If the form was submitted, the page would be refreshed, and the inputs values would be empty then. 
In this case, the solution would be to get the sent values with PHP, and then use these values directly in Javascript, like that :

```
var room_value_sent = '<?php echo $_REQUEST['room']; ?>';
fields_content += "room : " + room_value_sent  + "\n";
```

The `return false` at the end is because of the need not to submit the form. When you do something like `onsubmit="return my_function();"`, if `my_function` returns `false` then the form is not submitted (= no page refresh and no request is done).

Comment: I have added an ID to the textarea of id="my_textarea" and then placed your code in the script tag in head but nothing.

Comment: Add it at the end of your own script. Be careful not to `return` before. I edit my answer to be clearer.

Comment: Ok I see what's the problem. Your form is submitted, so the page is refreshed. Here, my code gets values directly from inputs. These inputs are empty when the page is reloaded. That's the point. Do you really need your form to be submitted ? If yes, you will have to use php to get the sent values.

Comment: Dont you have to submit the form to validate it via the onsubmit?

Comment: Yes. When you return a value in submit handler like you do it here, if the returned value is false, the form is not submitted : your javascript is executed, but the page is not refreshed. I just edited my answer.

Comment: So there is no way to do this without php? Meaning, you cannot write the values of the inputs to the textarea without php

Comment: Yes you can, if you do not submit your form, as I said. have a look at this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/qg43b/

Comment: ahhhh my apologies...I did not see the return false. That does the trick! Of course no one actually uses a form like this since you can just use php, but Im just learning :) Thanks.

Comment: Yes, i'm OK with that. I'm glad I could help you. Don't forget to mark this answer as accepted if you are happy with it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for answering instead of commenting - repuration limitations. You can try using Parsley.js library which provides clean code and works out of the box for almost any form you can imagine. Have a look here:

[Parlsey.js](http://parsleyjs.org/)